# How to manipulate data before Up() drops a column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am removing a property from a model but i wish to "work" on the removed data during the Up() method in the appropriate migration class.

Is there a way to access the column that Up() is about to drop and extract the data to some temporary collection and then manipulate it (insert it into another column, etc.) ?

Comment: Please only use tags that are relevant to your question, thank you.

Comment: Make sure you prevent data loss. Which means that at no moment in time data only exist in memory. You better insert the data in a temporary table which is dropped if the migration succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom query and call it like

```
 this.Sql( "query goes here" );
```

This can sound tedious but sometimes if your migrations alter the metadata, there is no other way than handcrafted sql to access the data that the migration is about to change.